# Is "Count++" the only way to use count?

Tags: c#

was wondering if I could get `count+2` somehow?

To get every second number, I am very new to programming and this is my first post

Edit: OK, thanks guys I got this, gonna try to multiply and stuff, gonna check this method

```
count += 2
```

Edit 2: Actually guys this problem is not supposed to be `+=2`, its supposed to be every odd number, TI: `1, 3, 5, 7`. So if I would input 1-6 it would go 1, 3, 5 anyone who bothers to help me?

Comment: And why exactly are you trying to accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried count = count + 2?

Comment: I'm guessing he's trying to add 2 in some type of for loop. It's not uncommon to see `for (int i = 0; i < someValue; i += 2) { ... }`

Comment: Maybe there should be a language feature where to increment by 2 you could go `n++++` and to increment by 10 you'd do `n++++++++++++++++++++`. `;)`

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: oh yes - then i could draw and code at the same time. That would be perfect for [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2188/3820) :)

Comment: For odd numbers, do this: `for (int Count=1; Count<100; Count += 2)`

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do?

```
Count += 2;

Count = Count + 2;
```

(Note that `Count` can be replaced by any (numeric) variable)

For example:

```
for (int Count=1; Count <= 7; Count+=2){
    Console.WriteLine(Count.ToString());
}

Output:
1,3,5,7
```

Comment: Well I just want the same as Count++ but change it so instead of going

1
2
3
4
5

It goes

1
3
5
7

Comment: Ok, then either of these (or all the other answers here) will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Count += n; //Where n is a value.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a for-loop, something like this:

```
    for (int Count=0; Count<10; Count++) 
    {
        // work with Count...
    }
```

then

```
Count++
```

is shorthand for:

```
Count = Count + 1
```

which could also be expressed as:

```
Count += 1
```

and so for an increment of 2 you could do:

```
Count += 2
```

or:

```
Count = Count + 2
```

To iterate over even numbers:

```
for (int Count=0; Count<10; Count += 2)
```

To Iterate over odd numbers:

```
for (int Count=1; Count<10; Count += 2)
```

(Note that the only difference evaluating even and odd numbers is the starting value.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not necessarily. With the omitted semicolon in the OPI thought that the increment is part of a for loop: `for (int i=0; i<10; i += 2)`

Comment: Actually, `++Count` is the same as `Count = Count + 1`. `Count++` has no longhand equivalent.

Comment: @Paul: Perhaps... but while `Count++;` and `Count = Count + 1;` do the same thing, `i = (Count++);` and `i = (Count = Count + 1);` do not.  These are not equivalent expressions, they just have equivalent side effects.

Comment: @aboveyou00: Sure it does, but it requires a temporary variable.

Comment: @Ben No, they're not the same. According to the C# specification, while both increment Count, one evaluates to the old value of Count and the other evaluates to the new.

Comment: @aboveyou00: I'm not sure what statement of mine you're disagreeing with, since that's actually what I said.

Comment: Oh, I see. But, I still disagree with you. There is no way to achieve the same CIL instructions as `++Count` with any other syntax, e.g. `ldloc.0 ldc.i4.1 add dup stloc.0`. Besides, you can't even use a temporary variable. How would you do it? `exprResult = ???`

Answer (score 1):

Yup, sure can:

```
Count += 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do for?

```
for (int i = 0; i < total; i+=2) {...}
```

Comment: yeah well acctually I have int x = start; x < stop; x+=2 {CW(x);}

Answer (score 0):

Let me think about, perhaps ....

```
int n = 5; int k = 5;
Increment(ref n, k);


private void Increment(ref int v, int c)
{
    if(c == 0) return;
    v++;
    Increment(ref v, --c);
}
```

Comment: I can make that extremely inefficient: `var n = Int32.MinValue; Increment(ref n, (Int32.MaxValue - Int32.MinValue));` :)